# how can I change a character to date-time type with ifelse?

Tags: r, date, datetime, tidyverse

Suppose I want to convert a number such "43843" to a date-time format （file read from excel, so some file is in correct date-time format; but others showed a character such as "43875", which is days from 1899-12-30）; but some are already in date-time type; so I used ifelse to judge the type of the column then apply the as.posixct function. but it seems does not work. I do not know why.

```
> tt <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-1-9","2020-2-1","2020-2-8"))
> dd1 <- tibble(tt,1:3)
> ts <- c("43843","43842","43844")
> dd2 <- tibble(tt=ts,1:3)
> dd1 %>% 
+     mutate(tt = ifelse(is.POSIXct(tt),tt,
+                        as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(tt), origin = "1899-12-30"))))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
          tt `1:3`
       <dbl> <int>
1 1578499200     1
2 1578499200     2
3 1578499200     3
> dd2 %>% 
+     mutate(tt = ifelse(is.POSIXct(tt),tt,
+                        as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(tt), origin = "1899-12-30"))))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
          tt `1:3`
       <dbl> <int>
1 1578873600     1
2 1578873600     2
3 1578873600     3
```

Comment: Where are you getting `is.POSIXct` from? I don't have such a function.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake; it is from {lubridate} package@thelatemail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more of an `if() else` problem than a vectorised `ifelse()` problem.
Be aware of timezone issues here as you are defining times in your system timezone, and also feeding data in that does not have an offset from GMT.

Anyway...

```
convfun <- function(x) {
  if(is.POSIXct(x)) {x} else {
    as.POSIXct(format(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x)*86400, origin="1899-12-30", tz="UTC")))
  }
}

dd1 %>% mutate(tt = convfun(tt))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  tt                  `1:3`
#  <dttm>              <int>
#1 2020-01-09 00:00:00     1
#2 2020-02-01 00:00:00     2
#3 2020-02-08 00:00:00     3

dd2 %>% mutate(tt = convfun(tt))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  tt                  `1:3`
#  <dttm>              <int>
#1 2020-01-13 00:00:00     1
#2 2020-01-12 00:00:00     2
#3 2020-01-14 00:00:00     3
```

Checking both in the same timezone:

```
(dd1 %>% mutate(tt = convfun(tt)))$tt
#[1] "2020-01-09 AEST" "2020-02-01 AEST" "2020-02-08 AEST"
(dd2 %>% mutate(tt = convfun(tt)))$tt
#[1] "2020-01-13 AEST" "2020-01-12 AEST" "2020-01-14 AEST"
```

Answer (score 1):

The values which are already in date-time type are still characters since a column can hold data of only one type so `is.POSIXct` would not work.  Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

dd2 %>%
   mutate(tt1 = replace(as.POSIXct(tt, format = "%Y-%m-%d %T"), 
                         grepl('^[0-9]*$', tt), NA), 
          tt = as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(tt), origin = "1899-12-30")),
          final = coalesce(tt1, tt))
```

This first creates a column (`tt1`) of `POSIXct` type which has values of data that have date and time and has `NA` for dates. We then change dates (which are numbers) to `POSIXct` format and then combine the columns using `coalesce`.

Comment: this does not work for dd1:

dd1 %>%
   mutate(tt1 = replace(as.POSIXct(tt, format = "%Y-%m-%d %T"), 
                         grepl('^[0-9]*$', tt), NA), 
          tt = as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(tt), origin = "1899-12-30")),
          final = coalesce(tt1, tt))
I want a function for both conditions because I do not know which condition I run into. I read hundreds of EXCEL file from disc.

Comment: @Z.Zhang If I use `dd1` from your example and run the above code final columns gives me `2020-01-09 00:00:00`, `2020-02-01 00:00:00` and `2020-02-08 00:00:00`. What is the output that you are expecting there?

Comment: yes, you are correct, I make a mistake; the code just works for me @Ronak Shah